# MacBook Pro: Can't change the screen brightness

Tags: display, applescript, settings

On my MacBook Pro 2012, I can't change the screen brightness. When I click on the brightness keyboard controls, nothing happens. Under System Preferences → Displays, the Brightness slider is missing:

[image: SP SS]

I have also tried with an AppleScript and when I run it, I hear an error sound:

```
tell application "System Events"
    key code 107
end tell
```

Where does the problem come from? How do I adjust the brightness?

Comment: Do the **F1** and **F2** _function keys_ work to control brightness? Note: Depending on **System Preferences** > **Keyboard**, you might have to press the **Fn** _key_ as well.  If  **[√] Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys** is checked you need to use **Fn** _key_ too.

Comment: @user3439894 i tried with both...

Comment: @user3439894 also the keys for the keyboard brightness are working

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Try using this app to adjust screen brightness: [Shades](http://www.charcoaldesign.co.uk/shades).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Restarting the Mac fixed the issue for me. I can now set the screen brightness alright.

Apparently it's a mysterious bug in macOS.

Update: @uzair-hayat pointed out that changing the Display Scale in Settings will bring back the brightness slider.

[image: Brightness Display Settings]

Comment: Thanks, just went through exactly the same thing on my mid-2014 Macbook - keys didn't work and brightness slider was missing from Displays panel. Catalina 10.15.5

Comment: While restarting would hopefully do the trick, another thing that worked for me is to change the Display Scale, after which things were back to normal for me.

Comment: Genius comment, yes, changing the scale helped me regain control of my brightness without a restart

Comment: @UzairHayat I confirm! - scale changing worked for me too! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue but after changing the 'PRESET' in the display section, I was able to update the brightness.